# TreeForm expression that will automatically spread nodes vertically so labels do not overlap

Tags: output-formatting, trees

My deeply and unevenly nested lists and equations generate a TreeForm image which is too small and compressed to use.  Then we must expand it manually by grabbing the edge of the image, and sometimes this requires irritating time and effort, and huge expansions.

Will some clever person please show me how to force the size of the TreeForm image to be large enough that no cells in the image overlap vertically?  So no level will vertically overlap any other level?

Then, in some instances, but not as important, a second option to force the image also to be large enough so no two cells on the same level overlap horizontally?  (This latter must be an option only, not the default, because the span may be extremely large horizontally for large databases.  Also, it might be best that partial overlaps be permitted.)

I imagine running TreeForm with these options, and then being able to use the vertical and horizontal scroll bars to see any part of the nested structure.

This would solve a lot of the problems being addressed by other solutions and questions about TreeForm.

Comment: The Pane idea is promising:  If someone knows how to specify vertical display size of a node, say y_Integer.  Then use something like Dimension[] to get the number of "levels", say d_Integer.  Then specify ImageSize-> 1.2 y d in TreeForm[] in place of ImageSize->1000.  (1.2 adds 20% extra vertical space for connecting lines.)  I don't know if TreeForm[] can accept a variable in place of the integer 1000, so just ruminating.

Comment: Hi! I see that you were visiting the site for some time now, but you voted scarcely and you never accepted an answer.  Please, when you see good questions and answers, **vote them up** by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to **accept** the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Pane`, e.g. (I used a random chunk of equation for example here):

```
Pane[TreeForm[(Abs[(mod - q2)*(q1 - lent*totalt)] + Abs[q2*(1 + q1 - lent*totalt)])/totalt, 
     ImageSize -> 1000], 
     ImageSize -> {600, 400}, Scrollbars -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this answers the primary question: how to *automatically* size to avoid overlapping labels.